# Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\{Project Name}.dll" because it was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, build

i want to learn Asp.net MVC and  when i apply the first program the VS2015 give me this error   "Could not copy the file "obj\Debug{Project Name}.dll" because it was not found" 
I tried to track this file before running the program and when running the app everything in path "obj\Debug\" deleted and recreate again but projectFile.dll not create and make this error

I have researched a lot and no solution

I try to reinstall the windows with fresh VS with update  3 same result

[image]

Comment: The error said that required project DLL file not found in `obj\Debug` directory. Can you include output window contents and project settings?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3813,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\test.dll" because it was not found.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: i didn't know what pro settings but i didn't change anything just i write three line 2 in control and 1 line in view to try it

 <div> 
        @ViewBag.g 
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

i find the reason that in .net framework i used 4.5.1 when converted it to 4.6.1 my project can build successfully